# how to use echarts with data from importing files

Tags: r, echarts

http://echarts.baidu.com/doc/example/line2.html

The above example is a multiple line chart, but in the series part:

```
series : [

    {
        name:'邮件营销',
        type:'line',
        stack: '总量',
        data:[120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
    {
        name:'联盟广告',
        type:'line',
        stack: '总量',
        data:[220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
    },
    {
        name:'视频广告',
        type:'line',
        stack: '总量',
        data:[150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
    },
    {
        name:'直接访问',
        type:'line',
        stack: '总量',
        data:[320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
    },
    {
        name:'搜索引擎',
        type:'line',
        stack: '总量',
        data:[820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
    }
]
```

It already knows how many lines it has and the data is listed.
I want to know if I use the data from an imported file, how can I draw a multiple line chart?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the "series" is a json object. You need to parse a valid json object by using HTTP request into your current page (you may want to use jQuery getJson method to communicate with your Java functions).

Next if your object is valid, the chart js engine will automatically draw lines and you dont need to worry about it.